# What is the meaning behind dark works often taking place at midnight?

Tags: tropes

A recurring story element that I've noticed is the accessibility of certain evil/dark devices at midnight.

A few examples:

1. In the [third episode](http://sailormoon.wikia.com/wiki/Mysterious_Sleeping_Illness!_Protect_the_Girls'_Hearts_in_Love) of *Sailor Moon*, girls listen to a midnight radio show that is hosted by the antagonists illegally. Girls that wrote into the show and are read on air receive a brooch which steals their energy.
2. In *[Persona](http://megamitensei.wikia.com/wiki/Midnight_Channel)*, there is a midnight channel which broadcasts the shadow of the person that is currently missing.
3. In *[Jigoku Shoujo](http://myanimelist.net/anime/228/Jigoku_Shoujo)*, there is a website that is only accessible at midnight, which will allow the user with a grudge to send someone to hell.

Why do all three of these anime use midnight as a time for evil? What is special about midnight that sets it apart from any other time?

Comment: Come on. Midnight is a time obviously privileged by the fact that it is, as the name suggests, in the middle of the night. If night is spooky and evil, then clearly midnight - the most nightish of all times - is the most spooky and evil.

Comment: its not really limited to japanese culture, either. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witching_hour

Answer (score 5):

This is an example of [pathetic fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathetic_fallacy), more specifically an [empathic environment](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EmpathicEnvironment). i.e. giving an environment a percieved emotion. It is a common literary technique.

Some other examples include:

- Rainy scenes when a character dies / delves into depression.
- A calm breeze after turmoil has subsided.
- A big storm buffets the castle walls as the evil king rages
- The sun appears from the clouds as the characters see a new path to follow after being downtrodden
- It snows and the land is harsh when a man is exiled from the city.

In this case, midnight - is commonly associated with spookiness, feelings of unease and the supernatural.

It also conjures images of darkness, which is commonly associated with evil - where light is usually a good force.

Comment: I would be really interested to know if this association came from Western influence or if it existed in pre-contact Japanese literature.

Comment: @Evilloli I don't know for sure, but I believe a lot of Japanese poetry like Haikus feature the seasons/setting almost as a character